# Is there a way to upload to AWS S3 without the file going to the temp directory using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, temp

I have been uploading big video files to AWS S3 but the videos are filing up my temp folder...

And I was wondering if I could just simply upload the video straight to AWS S3, I am aware of the HTML5 way but I also need to to insert the filenames, filesizes, etc. to the database...

The files are around 2 GB to about 6GB...

**HERE IS A CODE EXAMPLE**

```
$response = $s3->create_object("bucket_name", "filename.mp4", array(
'fileUpload'=>$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'],
'acl'=>AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
));
```

Comment: I think you can use nginx or any other webserver as reverse proxy, to buffer the file directly into an s3 bucket.

Comment: Frondor is right that you can use any reverse proxy.  If you need to do other things in PHP first (like authorizing user login to your site), be aware that uploads are often streamed or uploaded in chunks, which you have to account for.  If PHP sees the entire file, it's because the file is uploaded to a temporary location.  You'll need to check for and stream the file *as it is uploading* to avoid temporary file storage

Answer (score 0):

1. Request a signed URL from the Amazon S3 service.
2. Then upload directly using the signed URL

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/

[image]